# Object has no method 'ajaxLoader'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an asp.net mvc razor project. I want to use [AjaxLoader](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxloader/) in it.

Here are the files I incluse in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.ajaxloader.js")
```

And all the paths are correct. 
Here is how I use it:

```
$('<div id="myLoadingMask" style="width:300px; height:200px;"></div>').appendTo($('#myDiv'));
var $loadingMask = $("#myLoadingMask");
$loadingMask.ajaxLoader();
```

And I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxLoader'.Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `ajaxLoader` method is actually called [`ajaxloader`](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxloader/):

```
$loadingMask.ajaxloader();
```

Comment: Can you check for any error messages and the value of `$.fn.ajaxloader`?

Comment: $.fn.ajaxloader is undefined.

Comment: Can you try setting a breakpoint inside ajaxloader at the line with `jQuery.fn.ajaxloader = function()...`? Is the value set afterwards? Could it be that you are loading jQuery twice?

Comment: I removed the @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"). Still the same error.

Comment: Did you try the breakpoint idea? Do you have a link to the code?